# Translating specific text in html with a button

Tags: javascript, html, translation

I am trying to make a website that includes tweets in a foreign language and I want to make a button that will translate that tweet. The only tutorials I can find include having a google translate drop down list which translates everything on the page and isn't what I'm looking for. I would be looking for something similar to this:

```
<p id="demo">Aujourdhui jai promené mon chien</p>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = -->translate text here<--;
    }           
</script>

<p class=btnText onClick="myFunction()">Translate Button</p>
```

I just want my button that I already have on the page to translate the text when pressed, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There aren't free options for that service except google translator.

Comment: @Riven Is there a way of using google translate without having a dropdown list to choose your language though? So the default is English and the button uses google translate to do that instead

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google translate api.